# How To Forward HTML Email without Changing Styling

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail

I'm currently attempting to Forward an email from outlook to mobile and when I do so the styling goes away. Meaning, the text decoration that was initially set with an importance of none seems to go away. Any links seems to reappear with an underline

I say reappear because my code works just fine if you're opening the code via mobile gmail or IOS, or any large screen destop including outlook. it's when the code/email is shared/forwarded from outlook to mobile that the links appear with an underline

I've tried editing the styling setting an importance...

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    td {
      width:700px !important;
      position:static !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
    }
  }</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes email clients can be tricky as to how they read the HTML. You can try to put the **"text-decoration: none !important;"** property into the inline styling of the HTML. What mobile client are you trying to target?